# Do units heal faster in your own territory?

Tags: civilization-6

Do units heal faster in your own territory and more still in your cities?

If yes - where did you get this information, and by how much outside territory, inside territory, and in city?

"heal" and "healing" have no Civilopedia entries (srsly). I can find nothing on Google.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, though I can't find anything in the Civilopedia either.

From my experience units heal the following amount per turn:

- 20 in your own cities
- 15 in friendly territory (I think this includes friendly city states, but I'm not sure)
- 5 if units are healing in enemy territory
- 10 elsewhere

<strike>As in earlier games naval units can't heal outside of friendly territory (though this can be enabled with certain promotions).</strike>

Other factors that affect unit healing include:

- The "God of Healing" Pantheon (+30 healing in or adjacent to your Holy Site districts)
- The "Medic" industrial era support unit (boosts healing of adjacent units)
- An Apostle promotion that lets them heal units in the same way as a Medic
- The "Dead Sea" natural wonder (units heal completely in one turn)
- The Great Scientist, "Abu al-Qasim al-Zahrawi" (passive healing + retirement effect)

Comment: thx - are you sure about boats I thought I saw mine heal outside my territory but can't check now was a few days ago.

Comment: The Apostle also features a promotion that lets them heal nearby units as a medic would.

Comment: I swear my boats have had the option "rest and repair" even when outside friendly territory.

Comment: OK, now I'm not sure about the boat thing, I'll remove until I can re-check

Comment: Some ships, particularly including the Norwegian unique unit Viking Longboat, can heal in neutral territory. Most can't.

Comment: I find that English ships can 'rest and repair' outside friendly territory too - not sure if this is unique to England?

Comment: Looks like it was because I was Norway at the time. 
Now I am playing as China, and my Galley's "Rest and Repair" button is greyed out and says in red "Cannot heal outside friendly territory".

Comment: just to clear the issue, it's a unique feature for england and norway to rest and repair their ships outside of their territory.

Comment: I added an edit because I've observed units healing at a rate of 5 per turn within enemy territory. This was on Marathon speed but it probably doesn't matter.

Comment: A note - they heal at 5 not just in enemy territory - but in any other civ or city state's territory (maybe not if allies or suzerain - not sure about that?).

Comment: But do they have to be in the exact central spot, where the city is or range of the city, and the spot is the same?